# EJB - RIGHT_JOIN_NOT_SUPPORTED

Tags: java, jsp, jpa

soy nuevo en esto del uso de criteria y jpa.

Tengo dos tablas relacionadas por un campo. Necesito hacer un join que me muestre todos los datos relacionados así como los no relacionados por ese campo aunque algunos de los campos de la tabla principal se muestren vacíos (Así es el requerimiento, supongo que quieren detectar dicha información para identificar los faltantes de dicha relación). La relación de dichas tablas es uno a uno.

Mi tabla "principal" es cmb_cambios_configuracion la cual obtiene datos de otra tabla usando un campo para relacionarse con ella.

Tengo una consulta SQL que muestra dicha tabla como la necesito, sin embargo al intentar "traducirla" a criteria me tira una excepción de que el tipo del join no es soportado.

```
select *
from cmb_cambios_configuracion setup right outer join cmb_cambios pm
on setup.idcmb_cambios = pm.idcmb_cambios
where setup.idcmb_cambios is null 
OR setup.idcmb_cambios is NOT null;
```

mi consulta la hago de la siguiente manera:

```
 public List<CmbCambiosConfiguracion> arranqueDatos(Marca marca) {

    List<Predicate> predicateList = new ArrayList();
    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery cq = cb.createQuery();

    Root root = cq.from(getEntityClass());
    Join<CmbCambiosConfiguracion,CmbCambios> join = root.join(CmbCambiosConfiguracion_.cmbCambios, JoinType.RIGHT);

    cq.select(root);
    predicateList.add(cb.isMember(marca, root.get(CmbCambiosConfiguracion_.cmbCambios).get(CmbCambios_.serial).get(PrnPartnumber_.marca)));
    Predicate esNulo = cb.isNull(join.get(CmbCambios_.CmbCambiosConfiguracion));
    Predicate noNulo = cb.isNotNull(join.get(CmbCambios_.CmbCambiosConfiguracion));
    predicateList.add(cb.or(esNulo, noNulo));

    cq.where(cb.and(getPredicates(predicateList)));
    cq.orderBy(cb.asc(root.get(CmbCambiosConfiguracion_.fechaCreacion)));
    Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
    return q.getResultList();
}
```

y la excepcion que obtengo es la siguiente

```
Advertencia:   A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB CmbCambiosConfiguracionFacade, method: public java.util.List org.cardon.database.ejb.CmbCambiosConfiguracionFacade.arranqueDatos(org.cardon.database.entity.Marca)
Advertencia:   javax.ejb.EJBException
.
.
.
.
.
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: RIGHT_JOIN_NOT_SUPPORTED (There is no English translation for this message.)
```

Como les comento aun soy demasiado inexperto y ya le he dedicado varias horas a investigar como hacerlo y solo he encontrado que esto no esta soportado por JPA. Les agradezco de antemano sus respuesta y les pido una disculpa si no he sido muy claro.

Answer (score 0):

Te está diciendo que no soporta un "right join":

```
 Join<CmbCambiosConfiguracion,CmbCambios> join = 
       root.join(CmbCambiosConfiguracion_.cmbCambios, JoinType.RIGHT);
```

Prueba a cambiar ésto a otro tipo, por ejemplo da la vuelta al orden del join y conviértelo en un LEFT:

```
select *
from cmb_cambios_configuracion setup right outer join cmb_cambios pm
on setup.idcmb_cambios = pm.idcmb_cambios
```

es lo mismo que

```
select *
from cmb_cambios pm left outer join cmb_cambios_configuracion setup
on pm.idcmb_cambios = setup.idcmb_cambios
```

Comment: ¿Por cual otro tipo lo puedo cambiar? He intentado utilizar LEFT pero esto únicamente me trae los datos que están relacionados mediante el campo de id de la otra tabla.

Comment: Añadido a la respuesta

Comment: De hecho ya había intentado hacer la siguiente query y me entrega los datos como los necesito (almenos eso creo)

    select *
    from cmb_cambios pm left outer join  cmb_cambios_configuracion setup 
    on setup.idcmb_cambios = pm.idcmb_cambios
    where setup.idcmb_cambios is null 
    OR setup.idcmb_cambios is NOT null;

Comment: Perdona por el mal formato del la query, es que aun no estoy familiarizado sobre como insertar el bloque de código en los comentarios. Con lo que mencione anteriormente no estoy seguro como implementar esa query mediante CRITERIA. ¿tengo que hacer otro root para poder hacer dicho join? ¿una vez hecho el join mi criteria podra rescatar los datos pese a que el root es de otra tabla? (Lamento si no soy claro)